# How to perform zipped mirroring on Windows?

Tags: windows, sync, automation, shell-script, zip

My source is a directory hierarchy. I need to auto-copy the files in the source to a destination directory, but to have each file individually zipped inside the destination sub-directories. Furthermore, files which weren't changed since the last sync shouldn't be zipped/synced redundantly.

How can I perform such zipped mirroring?

Comment: Sounds like a custom backup solution ;-) Did you look at backup tools, they usually compress as well. The free Cobian Backup (http://www.cobiansoft.com/index.htm) even compresses to ZIP.

Answer (score 0):

7zip is very useful from a bat script.

You should be able to achieve directory mirroring with it. It supports creating a base archive, and then updating it with only files that have changed. http://hackerspa.com/differential-backups-in-windows-with-7zip/

As for 'each file individually zipped'... - you would need an elaborate vbs or powershell script to achieve that...